# Casting Tab - Fullscreen Video

Tags: google-chrome, video, google-chrome-extension, fullscreen, chromecast

While casting a tab, fullscreen videos will be resize to fit the current window. Is it possible to achieve this with a chrome extension?

What changes in the tab if you cast it? Is there some open-source code of the casting API?

Reproduce:

1. Chromecast a tab with video inside.
2. Fullscreen video.
3. Video will be resize to fit window.

Comment: What does your code look like that doesn't work? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: I do not have a code for that. I just noticed that chromecast fullscreen the video to fit the browser. I want to know how they do that because I tried to achieve this with a chrome extension a while ago. But it was not very flexible.